# Calling .NET superclass method in Matlab

Tags: .net, matlab, types

stackers,

Right now I am facing up one issue which concerned on calling .NET methods in Matlab. The relative reference can be found through link below:

[http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6.html][1]

My issue is that when I get the object from .net, I want to call its superclass's method. So it means that I want to cast the type to its super parent's type.

Image that I got objectA from .net calling in matlab, the class of objectA is the child of objectB, my intention should be like the below line of code:

**objectB = cast(objectA, 'parent class type')**

It does not work, any helps or comments on it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the superclass an actual class type or an interface?  Show some example code.

Comment: so in general, my target is to call one .net library in matlab. That .net library has lots of hierarchical oo structure. After adding assembly and retrieve one child object in matlab, my next intention is to call that child's parent's class method, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in the parent (superclass or base) type are inherited, and can be called on an object of the subtype.

Or are you trying to call the base class version of a virtual method?  You cannot do that from outside the class.

Comment: I also have a look at this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brenyev-1.html, but it seems to construct all of its oo classes in matlab. But in my case, it is not.